# VNC resolution mismatch

Tags: windows-8, resolution, vnc, tightvnc

I am running vncserver on Ubuntu with `vncserver -geometry 1920x1080` (the same resolution as my Windows 8 laptop)

Then I access the server using TightVNC Viewer, which is full screen and set to 100% zoom.

However it is being cropped and showing scroll bars. The virtual desktop is clearly significantly larger than the screen size of my laptop.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf358.jpg]

What is going on??

Comment: It's hard to measure pixels here, so can you post a pic proving that you're really running the laptop at 1920x1080?  That seems high-res for a laptop, unless it's a 15-in screen or larger.  Anyway, assuming you're right about the laptop res, are you sure you're connecting to the right vncserver?  In other words, there could be 2 running, and you're connecting to the a "default" vncserver, not the one you spawned with the `-geometry` option.  Check the port ("5901", etc) that should be shown after the VNC server launches.

Comment: Proof of resoution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A1cZj.png Yes, I am sure about the server, there is a native vnc server as well but it has a completely different desktop/icons etc. As you can see, this is one that is running on an account I have just set up. It is running on display :1 so I connect to it with port 5901.

Comment: After viewing this: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28310-dpi-scaling-size-change-displays-windows-8-1-a.html I set my vncserver to 1536x864 (80% of full resolution) and it now fits perfectly.

Comment: BTW measuring pixels?? Just open image in new tab and BOOM its right there in the title LOL